# Change color of UIImage with more than one color in it

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uiimage

I need to change the color of a UIImage.

But this image have 2 colors, one is kind a border and the other is the white at the center center.

[image]

The white must remain unchanged, but the other color will be changed in code..

I've tried some things such:

`let orImage = UIImage(named: "HomeImg")
self.imgViewPin.image = orImage?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
self.imgViewPin.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()`

Also extensions to UIImage

```
extension UIImage {
func imageTintedWithColor(color:UIColor) -> UIImage {
    var img:UIImage!

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, 0.0)
    var rect = CGRect.zero
    rect.size = self.size

    self.drawInRect(rect)
    color.set()
    UIRectFillUsingBlendMode(rect, .ColorBurn)
    self.drawInRect(rect, blendMode: .SourceIn, alpha: 1.0)

    img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return img
}

func tintedImageWithColor(color:UIColor) -> UIImage {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, 0.0)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: self.size)
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, CGBlendMode.Normal)
    self.drawInRect(rect)

    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, CGBlendMode.SourceIn)
    color.setFill()

    CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}}
```

I even tried changing pixel per pixel but the effect is not good.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Make an attempt and come back here with specific questions. "Write my code for me" is not an acceptable question. Check here if you have questions about what makes a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry about that, I have changed the question to detail my main problem that would also solve the one of the map.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to get this effect is to make your image with all the white areas solid white and with the coloured areas set as transparent

Now you can just change the background colour which will shine through the transparent bits, and there you have your colour changing icon! :)

Comment: But if the area outside the colored are in also transparent the effect would be applied to everything. So the result would be a square with the desired color with a rounded white circle in the middle, so the map pin format would be lost.

Comment: Yeah my technique will only work when you don't require actual transparent areas too